# Case insensitive sub-string search

Tags: algorithm, c, strings, search

I found myself in a need of a function that checks whether a string is a sub-string of another string, in a case-insensitive manner. I found that there's no standard function to do this, so I wrote my own.

Please review for bugs / improvements:

```
char *istrstr(char *str, const char *substr)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    while (*str) {
        while (str[n] && substr[n]) {
            if (tolower(str[n]) != tolower(substr[n])) {
                break;
            }
            n++;
        }
        if (!substr[n]) {
            return str;
        }
        else if (!str[n]) {
            return substr[n] ? str : NULL;
        }
        n = 0;
        str++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: you're aware that this doesn't even handle "simple" UTF-8 based comparison weirdnesses? What kinds of strings does this code handle?

Comment: What does the method name `istrstr` mean?

Comment: @D.Everhard "insensitive string in str", based on [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr).

Comment: @Vogel612 The same as `strstr`, so… byte strings (no encoding specified).

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Zeta I totally understand, but I didnt edit that line based on a feedback in an answer. I edited because of a simple blunder/typo.

Comment: @machine_1 that's a [comment from this list](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/frequently-posted-comments); either way, editing would now invalidate Toby's answer. I've asked on [chat because I wasn't sure either](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=41163572#41163572). Feel free to ask on [meta] if you think the rollback was not correct. Can't blame you, by the way. Broken code is off-topic, and off-topic questions shouldn't get answers, but some bugs (or typos) will only be found during review. The answer invalidations are therefore somewhat our fault, too.

Comment: @Zeta, I'm inclined to be generous with code that's broken because of insufficient testing (in those cases, the review often starts with "improve the tests").  I'll reject *known-broken* code, because we're not Stack Overflow and "help me fix this" is *clearly* off-topic.

Comment: @TobySpeight right. The `x ? y : z` "bug" wasn't known at the time the question was up for review and was found by review. _That_ is completely on-topic. After all, finding bugs can be part of a review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obscure bug when `CHAR_MIN < 0`.

`islower(int ch)` is only valid when `ch` has a value in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`.  As `char` may have various negative values, `tolower(str[n])` can be *undefined behavior* (UB).

> ... In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.  C11dr §7.4 1

```
tolower(str[n]) != tolower(substr[n]) // UB
// replace with
tolower((unsigned char) str[n]) != tolower((unsigned char) substr[n])
```

---

Small simplification.

Use the property that when `ch != 0`, then `tolower(ch) != 0`.  Then code need not check `str[n]` and `substr[n]`

```
while (str[n] /* && substr[n] */) {
  if (tolower((unsigned char) str[n]) != tolower((unsigned char) substr[n])) {
    break;
  }
...
```

---

Use `const` for `str` too.  Wider application and some optimizations may be had.

```
// char *istrstr(char *str, const char *substr)
char *istrstr(const char *str, const char *substr)
```

---

Rarely are **micro optimizations** worth the effort, yet this may be one of those exceptions.

Functions like `istrstr()` or `my_strcmp_caseless()` may be used **a lot** and so warrant "tricks" (AKA micro-optimizations) not meant for normal code as they are higher maintenance yet may provide meaningful improved performance in select cases.

Use with caution.

One is to take advantage that the usually 256 different `char` values are mapped to a smaller than 256 set.  So by using two `tolower()` functions: perhaps 256 byte look-up tables that differ only in `my_tolower[0] != my_tolower0[0]`, then the compare for a null character is not needed, simplifying the crucial inner loop.  Further, I found many compilers perform pre-increment faster than post increment.

```
 unsigned char my_tolower[256] = { '\0', 1, ... , 'a', 'b', ... 'a', 'b', ... };
 unsigned char my_tolower0[256] = { 'A', 1, ... , 'a', 'b', ... 'a', 'b', ... };

int my_strcmp_caseless(const unsigned char *a, const unsigned char *b) {
  // different lookup tables
  if (my_tolower[*a] == my_tolower0[*b]) {
    while (my_tolower[*(++a)] == my_tolower0[*(++b)]) {
    }
  }
  // same lookup table
  return my_tolower[(unsigned char) *a] - my_tolower[(unsigned char) *b];
}

char *istrstr2(const char *str, const char *substr) {
  while (*str) {
    if (my_strcmp_caseless((const unsigned char *) str), 
        (const unsigned char *) substr) == 0) {
      return str;
    }
    str++;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Of course, *locale* issues need attention to proper populate and maintain `my_tolower[], my_tolower0[]`.

Answer (score 5):

Both arguments should be `const char*`. It's a search, it shouldn't be able to change `str` by accident.

Let's have a look at its use, though. Does it really work like `strstr`?

```
puts(istrstr("example", "please")); // prints "ple"
```

`istrstr`'s behaviour completely differs from [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr). The latter will return NULL when the second string isn't ***completely*** in the first one. `istrstr`'s name is therefore misleading and should be called `istringoverlap` or similar.

Unless you're going for performance, I suggest you to go for simplicity and write an additional helper:

```
/** @brief checks whether @a prefix is a prefix of @a str.
 *
 * @param str    a null-terminated string
 * @param prefix a null-terminated string
 * @returns 1 if @a prefix is a prefix of @a str
 * @returns 0 otherwise
 *
 * The check is case-insensitive.
 *
 * This function yields undefined behavior if tolower() yields undefined 
 * behavior for any character in either str or prefix. If @a str
 * or @a prefix is not a null-terminated string, the behavior will be
 * undefined.
*/
int is_iprefix(const char * str, const char * prefix) {
    while(*str && *prefix) {
        if(tolower(*str) != tolower(*prefix)) {
            return 0;
        }
        prefix++;
        str++;
    }
    return (*prefix == '\0');
}
```

Why would I recommend to write another function? With only seven lines it's easy to check whether we got that right. We can re-use this function if we want to, and we can use it as a building block for our now `istrstr` variant:

```
const char * istrstr(const char * str, const char * substr) {
    while(*str) {
        if(is_iprefix(str,substr)) {
            return str;
        } else {            /* not really necessary, since return exits */
            str++;
        }    
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

However, that's not going for maximum performance. If we're really interested in more performance, we have to stop as soon as `str` is shorter than `substr`. We can either use `strlen` and count down, e.g.

```
const char * istrstr(const char * str, const char * substr) {
    int diff = strlen(str) - strlen(substr);
    while(*str && diff-- >= 0) {
        if(is_iprefix(str,substr)) {
            return str;
        } else {
            str++;
        }    
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

or we can inline `is_iprefix` and check whether `str` runs out of characters, but that's left as an exercise. Your code is almost there, by the way, you just need to fix the aforementioned bug.

Comment: `while(*str && *prefix)` can be reduced to `while(*str)` given a null character should not match any case letter.

Comment: @zeta -- cool answer. What code editor/ide do you use that (I think?) that helps you document/comment the functions?

Comment: @David542 I wrote the [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) comments by hand, IIRC, but several C and C++ editors and IDEs provide support for Doxygen. E.g. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen, https://frankmeffert.de/emacs-doxygen-doxymacs/ or https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=987.

Answer (score 3):

### Algorithm

There are more efficient string searching algorithms than this; if performance is important, you should research them.

Also, consider whether `tolower()` is really what you want for a case-insensitive comparison - it's fine for the C locale, but in some locales, both `e` and `é` are equivalent to `E`, in which case, comparing the results of `tolower()` will miss matches and comparing `toupper()` will produce false positives.

### Includes

The code is missing definitions for `size_t`, `NULL` and `tolower()`.  It needs

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

### Interface

All names beginning with `is` are reserved for future use by the standard library; so declaring `istrstr()` is Undefined Behaviour.  Similarly, we can't call it `stristr()` or similar; we could safely call it `i_strstr` if you want.

The standard library `strstr()` accepts `str` as a `const char*`.  Even though it returns a pointer to non-`const` and thus creates a hole in the type system, it's probably better to be consistent with that implementation, to avoid surprising users.

### Logic

There's a redundant test here:

```
    if (!substr[n]) {
        return str;
    }
    else if (!str[n]) {
        return substr[n] ? str : NULL;
    }
```

We only reach the `else` branch if `substr[n]` is true, so we don't need to re-test it:

```
    if (!substr[n]) {
        return str;
    }
    else if (!str[n]) {
        return str;
    }
```

However, this still looks incorrect - if we ran out of `str` while there's still some `substr` remaining to check, then we didn't find a match; this fails the `abcdefg` and `efg` tests in my test program (below).  We want to return `NULL` in that case:

```
    if (!substr[n]) {
        return str;
    }
    else if (!str[n]) {
        return NULL;
    }
```

Alternatively, just omit the `else` - we'll fall through to returning NULL before long anyway.

We can stop the loop when `str` is too short to contain `substr`:

```
const size_t substr_len = strlen(substr);
if (strlen(str) < substr_len)
    return NULL;

while (str[substr_len]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

To further reduce unnecessary work when `str` is very long, we don't need to measure its full length - we can define a `shorter_than()` function which iterates until either string ends.  I wanted to call it `is_shorter()`, but as we've seen above, that's reserved for future Standard Library extension.

---

## Improved version

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

static int shorter_than(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    while (*a++ && *b)
        ++b;
    return *b;
}

char *i_strstr(const char *str, const char *substr)
{
    const size_t substr_len = strlen(substr);

    if (shorter_than(str, substr))
        return NULL;

    do {
        for (const char *p = str, *q = substr;  ;  ++p, ++q) {
            /* Have we matched all of substr */
            if (!*q)
                return (char*)str;
            /* Test the next char */
            if (tolower(*p) != tolower(*q))
                break;
        }
    } while (str++[substr_len]);

    return NULL;
}
```

### Test program

Note carefully that many of these tests are designed to exercise the edge cases, such as matching (or not) at the extreme ends of the string, or using empty strings as arguments.

I've purposefully not tested passing null pointers to the functions; I consider that a programming error and should document that it would be undefined behaviour.  Alternatively, we could add some appropriate tests, and adjust the code to pass them.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int expect(int val, const char *file, int line, const char *message, ...)
{
    if (!val) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, message);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d:fail: ", file, line);
        vfprintf(stderr, message, args);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        va_end(args);
    }
    return !val;
}

#define expect_true(a) expect((a), __FILE__, __LINE__, #a " should be true")
#define expect_false(a) expect(!(a), __FILE__, __LINE__, #a " should be false")
#define expect_equal(actual, expected) \
    expect((actual)==(expected), __FILE__, __LINE__, #actual " should be " #expected)

int main()
{
    static char p[] = "ABcdEF";
    static char z[] = "";
    /* Return the number of test failures */
    return 0
        + expect_false(shorter_than("a", "a"))
        + expect_false(shorter_than("ab", "a"))
        + expect_true(shorter_than("a", "ab"))
        + expect_false(shorter_than("", ""))
        + expect_false(shorter_than("a", ""))
        + expect_true(shorter_than("", "a"))
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, ""), p)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, "ABC"), p)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, "abcdef"), p)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, "bc"), p+1)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, "cd"), p+2)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, "ef"), p+4)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, "BA"), NULL)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, "abcdefg"), NULL)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(p, "efg"), NULL)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr("", p), NULL)
        + expect_equal(i_strstr(z, z), z)
        ;
}
```

Comment: `if (strlen(str) < substr_len)` is an expensive check as code is obliged to scan the entire `str`. This does not hurt worst case performance much, but consider long strings that often have a match.   Perhaps a `strlen_limited(str, substrlen)` that does not run passed `substrlen`?

Comment: @chux, I've updated with something loosely based on that suggestion.  I did first try `strnlen_s()` from Annex K, but that's not widely implemented - if you care for that, you can see it in the edit history.

Comment: `shorter_than()` is clever!